# как сделать между двумя TextView линию?

Tags: android

как сделать между двумя TextView линию ? [image: На подобии такого]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если это не список (ListView, RecyclerView и тп), а просто два виджета на разметке, между которыми нужно провести линию, то просто добавляешь между `TextView` `View` шириной в 1-2 dp и бэкграундом с нужным цветом (или градиентом,текстурой и  тп - вид разделителя может быть любым и использоваться любые возможности: 9-patch, xml-shape, изображения). Отступы от краев (если требуется) задаешь ему маржинами. Примерно так:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#7b7b7b"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#7b7b7b"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Для списков совсем другие способы - список поддерживает divider изначально.

Comment: Разделители в dp смотрятся некрасиво, лучше указывать в px. imho

Comment: Yura Ivanov плохой совет, в px где-то будет жирная полоса, а где-то и вовсе не будет видно разделителя.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь .

Answer (score 4):

Если хочешь чтобы код выглядел красиво, то лучше создать отдельно `separator.xml` в папке `res/drawable` и поместить туда следующий код:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#90909090" />
</shape>
```

и потом через `android:divider="@drawable/separator` в корневой layou

это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:divider="@drawable/separator"
    android:dividerPadding="4dp"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
```